# Large POD struct copy to stack crashes in a worker thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c++

iOS project in a mix of Obj-C++ and C++ proper. I have a POD struct about 1 MB in size. There is a global instance of it. If I create a local instance of the same in a function that is invoked on a worker thread, the copy operation crashes (when invoked from a worker thread) in debug builds on a simulator. The release builds don't crash.

This smells like running out of stack size.

The worker thread in question is not created manually - is an `NSOperationQueue` worker.

The questions are twofold:

- why does automatic stack growth fail?
- how does one increase stack size on `NSOperationQueue` threads?

---

The repro goes:

```
 
struct S
{
     char s[1024*1024];
};

S gs;

-(void)f
{
    S ls;
    ls = gs; //Crash!
}
```

---

Okay, I see about rewriting `NSOperationQueue` to grow the stack. That said - the **compiler (Clang) definitely has some kind of workaround for that. I'll check the disassembly just in case, but the same code doesn't crash in release builds. How come it's not engaging in this case? OBTW, checked the same code on Android, saw same crash.

---

PS: the motivating case is from not from my code, it's from a third party algorithm library. The original library doesn't really need a deep copy; the local variable is never written to, only read from; a reference (even a const one) would do just as well. My guess is that the author *wanted* a reference but messed it up. In the release build, the compiler optimizes is to a reference, thus no crash. In the debug build, it does not.

Comment: `I'll check the disassembly just in case, but the same code doesn't crash in release builds` If you play around with same exact code, any level of clang optimisation (but `-O0`) [discards it completely](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/KG8eWePKW), and release build in iOS by default has `-O3` flag.

Comment: Commonly if debug crashing but release is not, in release occurring undefined behaviour. For example debug is nullifing variables before usage. I suggest to turn on several Xcode's sanitisers.

Comment: In the original motivating fragment, the local copy of the global structure was never written to, so my guess is that the optimizer quietly replaced a copy with a reference. Technically not an undefined behavior. I don't think stack overflow is a UB. I've seen compilers move overlarge locals to a quietly allocated dynamic block to avoid this very scenario, but I guess not here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how up to date this documentation is, but [according to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW7) non-main threads top out at 512kiB stack size unless otherwise configured during thread creation.

I struggle to see a good reason to store such a data structure on the stack, particularly with (Obj-)C++ where you can easily wrap it in something like a `std::unique_ptr` which manages heap allocations and deallocations automatically. (Or indeed any other RAII based abstraction, or even storing it as an ivar in an ARC-enabled Objective-C class if you're so inclined.)

One downside to opting into very large stack sizes is that this memory likely stays resident but unused until the thread terminates, particularly on iOS where this memory won't even be swapped to disk. This is fine if you're explicitly starting up a thread and shut it down once you're done with your giant-stack-requiring-algorithm. But if you're running a one-off job on a pooled thread, you've now effectively leaked 1MB of memory. Maybe it's the embedded developer in me (or that I remember when iPhones only had 128MB RAM) but I'd prefer not to write code like that. (Or can someone come up with evidence that the low-memory warning mechanism purges unused stack space?)

Comment: It was not my code :)

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood the threading mechanism of Cocoa uses unix POSIX threads for which stack size follows the following rules:

- Default stack size, if it's not explicitly specified (e.g. in macOS you can find this value by running `ulimit -s` command, which for my machine is `8192` KiB, but for iOS is very likely a few times less)
- Arbitrary stack size if it's specified during creating of a thread

Answering your first question:

> - why does automatic stack growth fail?

It "fails" because it's not allowed to grow beyond the allocated size for a given thread. More interesting question in this case - why it doesn't fail for release build? And frankly I don't have an answer here. I **assume** it most likely has something to do with the optimisation, where the compiler is allowed to bypass certain memory flow routines or discard some parts of code completely.

---

For the second question:

> - how does one increase stack size on NSOperationQueue threads?

The main thread of an application always has the default system stack size, and can only be altered in macOS (or rooted iOS device) with use of `ulimit` (size is given in KiB):

```
# Sets 32 MiB default stack size to a thread
% ulimit -s 32768
```

All other threads (to my knowledge) under both iOS and macOS have their size specified explicitly and it equals to 512 KiB. You will have to somehow forward the stack size  to the [`pthread_create(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) function for them, something like this:

```objc++
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <pthread.h>

struct S {
    char s[1024 * 1024];
};

void *func(void *context) {
    // 16 MiB stack variable
    S s[16];
    NSLog(@"Working thread is finished");
    auto* result = new int{};
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    pthread_attr_t attrs;
    auto s = pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    // Allocates 32 MiB stack size
    s = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 1024 * 1024 * 32);

    pthread_t thread;
    s = pthread_create(&thread, &attrs, &func, nullptr);
    s = pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);
    void* result;
    s = pthread_join(thread, &result);
    if (s) {
        NSLog(@"Error code: %d", s);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Main is finished with result: %d", *(int *)result);
        delete (int *)result;
    }


    @autoreleasepool {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately neither of queue API (`GCD` or `NSOperation`) exposes allocation part of their thread pools, let alone that `NSThread` doesn't let you to specify your own `pthread` explicitly for underlying execution. If you want to rely on those APIs, you will have to implement it "artificially".

You can find a sample implementation of such an operation class in [the gist](https://gist.github.com/TheDreamsWind/49bc1d11817828d627d3968364b08d5e). Here is the minimal example of how it might be used:

```objc++
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <type_traits>
#import "TDWOpeartion.h"

struct S {
    unsigned char s[1024 * 1024];
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
        constexpr auto elementsNum = static_cast<std::size_t>(16);

        [queue addOperations:@[
            [[TDWOperation alloc] initWithExecutionBlock:^{
                using elemType = std::remove_all_extents_t<decltype(S::s)>;
                S arr[elementsNum];
                auto numOfElems = sizeof(S::s) / sizeof(elemType);
                for(decltype(numOfElems) i = 0; i < numOfElems; ++i) {
                    for (auto val: arr) {
                        val.s[i] = i % sizeof(elemType);
                    }
                }
                NSLog(@"Sixteen MiB were initialized");

            } stackSize:sizeof(S) * elementsNum * 2]
        ] waitUntilFinished:YES];
    }
    return 0;
}
```